# Django | 2 modelos y 1 formulario - No guarda respuesta de usuario en base de datos

Tags: python, django

Al tratar de mostrar contenido en un formulario y luego guardar las respuestas de cada usuario he planteado de la siguiente (seguramente incorrecta) manera, pero muestra la primera pregunta, pero no guarda la respuesta del usuario:
**¿Cual tipo de View se debería utilizar para no dar error?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Urls:**

```
path('test/<str:questionModality>/',
        views.testFilterByModalityAndByUserView.as_view(),
        name='test',
    ),
```

Views:

```
class testFilterByModalityAndByUserView(ListView):
    model = TestQuestion
    template_name = 'test/question.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        questionMod = self.kwargs['questionModality']
        print(questionMod)

        #name = self.request.GET.get('kword', '')
        if questionMod:
            object_list = TestQuestion.objects.all().filter(nameModality__name=questionMod).order_by('number')[:1]
        else:
            object_list = TestQuestion.objects.all()
        return object_list
    login_url = reverse_lazy('test_app:test')


    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                username = request.user
            ...
         #Guardar datos del formulario POST en la base de datos.
```

Models:

```
class TestQuestion(models.Model):
    ANSWER=(('1','A'),('2','B'),('3','C'),('4','D'))
    number=models.IntegerField('Nº',null=True,blank=True)
    question=models.TextField('Pregunta',null=True,blank=True)
    a=models.TextField('A',null=True,blank=True)
    b=models.TextField('B',null=True,blank=True)
    c=models.TextField('C',null=True,blank=True)
    d=models.TextField('D',null=True,blank=True)
    answer=models.CharField('Respuesta',max_length=1,choices=ANSWER, null=True, blank=True)
    nameModality=models.ForeignKey(Modality,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    observations=models.TextField('Observaciones',null=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Test'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Test'
        ordering = ['number']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)


class UserAnswers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    modality = models.ForeignKey(Modality,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    numberQuestion = models.IntegerField('Número pregunta',null=True,blank=True)
    datetimeAnswer=models.IntegerField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta correctamente',null=True,blank=True)
    wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta incorrectamente',null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.numberQuestion

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('test_app:test-hacertest', args=[self.user])
```

**Template:**

```
<form class="form-signin p-1" action="{% url 'test_app:test-process' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      

    {% for tes in object_list %}
  <div class="text-center mb-4">
    <h3 class="h4 mb-3 font-weight-normal text-secondary">{{ tes.nameModality }}</h3>
  </div>      
  <div class="text-left mb-4">
    <h3 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">{{ tes.number }}.-{{ tes.question }}</h3>
  </div>


  <div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label class="ml-4">
      <input id="idCheckboxA" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="A" name="fooby[1][]" /><a id="aidCheckboxA"> A .-{{ tes.a }}</a><br>
      <input id="idCheckboxB" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="B" name="fooby[1][]" /><a id="aidCheckboxB"> B .-{{ tes.b }}</a><br>
      <input id="idCheckboxC" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="C" name="fooby[1][]" /><a id="aidCheckboxC"> C .-{{ tes.c }}</a><br>
      <input id="idCheckboxD" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="D" name="fooby[1][]" /><a id="aidCheckboxD"> D .-{{ tes.d }}</a><br>
      <input id="Answer" style="visibility:hidden" type="hidden" value="{{ tes.get_answer_display }}"><br>
    </label>

 
{% endfor %}
  </div>
  
  <button id="nextButton" style="background-color:#250F64; color:white; display:none" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Siguiente</button>
  <a href="{% url 'home_app:home' %}"><p class="text-center mt-3">Volver a la página principal</p></a>

</form>
```

Comment: El problema está más en la relación en sí que en el tipo de vista. La relación entre `user` y `answers` es una relación muchos a muchos y la tabla intermedia (que tú aquí construyes explícitamente) debería contemplar la relación por estas entidades `UserAnswer.question = models.ForeignKey(Answer, …)`. La vista (CreateView) gestiona una UserAnswer, tanto para mostrar el formulario como para guardarlo.

Comment: Gracias, muy amable!. ¿Esa CreateView me permite filtrar la pregunta (correspondiente según filtros: por ejemplo según categoría, etc) antes de mostrar en el template? ¿Con "get_queryset" sería?

Comment: La vista en sí no hace más que proporcionar un mecanismo simple para gestionar un modelo. Por sí misma no es capaz de gestionar más que la `UserAnswer`. De hecho, al ser una vista para la creación de objetos tienes que implementar las restricciones que no estén en el modelo de datos (p.e. limitar una categoría) en sus métodos.

Comment: Al tener multitud de pregutas pensaba que tenía que utilizar una ListView con algún sistema de paginación por pregunta o algo de eso. La ListView sí me permite filtrar por categoría que le paso por url. Utilizo un get_queryset(self) y categoria = self.kwargs['questionModality']... y lo filtro con ello. Pero me temo que esto no sirve para guardar las respuestas de los usuarios. ¿Debería utilizar CreateView como dices tanto para filtrar lo que llevo a template como para guardar el base de datos lo que traigo a la view por post? gracias.

Comment: Para guardar cada respuesta utilizo una fila de la base de datos por cada respuesta: idUser, categoria, numPregunta, contaCorrecta, contaIncorrecta. Y si cada ver que la pregunta se repite al mismo usuario, debe aplicar un update para contabilizar las respuestas correctas e incorrectas. (Y poder sacar estadísticas de las preguntas que más ha costado aprender).

Comment: Si usas varias preguntas (que sería un test) quizás te convenga utilizar form y formsets (el form sería el test, formset las preguntas) si muestras varias pregutnas en una página. Si solo muestras una pregunta, deberás controlar los parámetros por URL (y obtener el usuario de la request)

Comment: Es una pregunta por cada vez, ya que en la view según la respuesta del usuario (con unas condiciones especificas) irá seleccionando la siguiente pregunta. Siempre sólo una pregunta cada vez. Según comentas, entonces por URL. En la view para esto utilizarías algún tipo de classview o diréctamente una función que haga seleccionar para llevar al template y después por post tomar la respuesta del usuario? Gracias.

Comment: Yo intento usar siempre vistas de clase. Lo que haría seguro es crear además el formulario para la clase (forms.ModelForm) porque eso me permite personalizarlo (añadir clases, o valores en los placeholders) y luego incluirlo en la plantilla de forma sencilla. Con una CreateView y el formulario lo que redefines es solo el método form.is_valid() de la vista para tomar el usuario de la request